# How to calculate the watthour with series of power input and time data

Tags: python

I have motor input power values and time values in seconds I want to calculate the watt-hour how to do that here is my data

```py
power_data = [500, 750, 1000, 800, 900]
time_data_seconds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So far I tried this:

```
watt_hours_data = [(power * time) / 3600 for power, time in zip(power_data, time_data_seconds)]

# Calculate the total watt-hours
total_watt_hours = sum(watt_hours_data)
print("Total watt-hours:", total_watt_hours)
```

But I dont have clarity whether this method is correct.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Stack Overflow question. You seem to be asking an engineering question.

Comment: Does the power level start at 0W at 0s? How does the power level vary in the periods between the readings? Until you can describe the behaviour of the power usage, everything else is assumptions and guesses.

Comment: @jared yes i am asking engineering questions, i want to predict the watt-hour of a motor for  given power input and time values

Comment: @appu That's off-topic for Stack Overflow. Your question seems to be if your math is correct. Stack Overflow is for coding questions, such as writing something more efficiently or fixing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is right. Energy in watt-hours is computed by multiplying power in watts by time in hours and your  division by 3600 is for converting the time to hours. The list `watt_hours_data` includes the energy values for each data point.  The total energy consumption over the given time period is calculated by summing up values in the list.

In case the power levels are not flat and change over time (assuming linearly), the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) can be used as a numerical integration method:

```
power_start = power_data[:-1]
power_end = power_data[1:]
time_intervals = np.diff(time_data_seconds)

avg_power = [(start + end) / 2 for start, end in zip(power_start, power_end)]
energy_watt_hours = [avg * time / 3600 for avg, time in zip(avg_power, time_intervals)]

total_watt_hours = sum(energy_watt_hours)
print("Total watt-hours:", total_watt_hours)
```

Comment: Assumes power levels are flat for the second-long intervals and then have a step change to the next interval's power level. In reality, power levels gradually change, and the op has provided no information about that.

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, in case the power levels are not flat and change over time, numerical integration is needed to calculate the energy consumption.

Comment: @TechSavvy how to calculate by numerical integration

Comment: @appu Assuming a linear change in power between data points, one way for doing numerical integration is [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

Comment: @appu Check out the updated answer for a simple numberical integration implementation.

Comment: This isn't C, explicitly looping to perform calculations is usually bad practice in Python. I would advise using `np.diff`.

Comment: @Guimoute I tried to demonstrate how the rule appears, and I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed your method is correct. This line

```
watt_hours_data = [(power * time) / 3600 for power, time in zip(power_data, time_data_seconds)]
```

is using list comprehension to calculate the watt_hourse_data list. The zip() function just allows you to loop over two lists, "power_data" and "time_data_seconds" (equal in length) in parallel. Then you are calculating the watt-hour correctly, like Tech Savvy said, for every item in those lists and storing it in the "watt_hours_data" list.

Comment: No their method is not correct. 900W from hour 4 to hour 5 = 900 Ws, not 900*5 Ws.